# need to delete several hundred thousand rows using IDs in text file

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a text file with several hundred thousand primary IDs of rows I need to delete from a MySQL database of ~20m rows. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load the text file into a temporary table. You can then join this table with the table you want to delete from.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE delete_ids (id INT);
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/ids.txt' INTO TABLE delete_ids;
ALTER TABLE delete_ids ADD INDEX (id);

DELETE t
FROM your_table AS t
JOIN delete_ids AS d ON t.id = d.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.

Missing the word TABLE in this line:

LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/ids.txt' INTO TABLE delete_ids;

Answer (score -1):

I guess that you can copy and paste all your ID's that you want to delete on the  Notepad++, separete by '', '' (e.g. --> ('1', '2')) and after that, run a Query like this one:

delete FROM test where id in ('1', '2', '3', '5', '35');

This should works.
Seeya,,,

Comment: Have you tried this with a list of several hundred thousand numbers?

Comment: The file is 23Mb, so I suspect it's just a bit too big for cut and paste